# How does composer get different versions from the same repository

Tags: git, version-control, composer-php, version

when I run `composer install` or `composer update`, and I specify a version number in `composer.json`, if the codebase on the vendor's end is the same, how does composer negotiate with git to get a certain version?  Does it have to do with version tags on the commit?  Also, how would I specify a version in my codebase at a certain point so this can be recognized by composer?

Answer (score 0):

For the `vendor` folder, it should be ignored by git (add in `.gitignore`). So git is not necessary to negotiate the version in vendor folder.

And if you want everyone use the specified version, you can [commit **composer.lock** in git](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#commit-your-composer-lock-file-to-version-control).

Comment: That really isn't the question I had.  Perhaps I misstated.  The question is, "Suppose a repo contains both version 1 and 2; how does composer know what to pull out of the the vendor's code when version 1 is specified? When version 2 is specified?'

Comment: Do you mean the version 1 and 2 for `composer.json` file? And when do you want to get the specified version, when executing `composer install`?